# Prove $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega} |x - y|^{-n-\alpha} dy\right)^q dx < +\infty $ for $q<1/\alpha$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ a bounded domain. Is it true that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \left(\int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus \Omega} |x - y|^{-n-\alpha} dy\right)^q dx < +\infty $$
for $q <1/\alpha$? That seems to be a reasonable guess, but I don't know how to prove it. Maybe some application of Fubini? Also, is this range sharp? Or can it be improved?

Comment: Can you include context and motivation for the question? What have you tried? Do you assume $\Omega$ has a smooth boundary? Did you calculate this when $\Omega$ is a ball?

Comment: @YuvalPeres Yes, we may assume $\Omega$ has a smooth boundary. To be honest, I'm in doubt even when $\Omega = (0,1)$

Comment: @YuvalPeres Yes, we may assume $\Omega$ has a smooth boundary. To be honest, I'm in doubt even when $\Omega = (0,1)$